# back to the parent page without changes in that page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hypavmat" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Merchandiser/MAddMaterial.aspx"
    Target="_blank" Visible="False">Click the link to select material</asp:HyperLink></td>
```

i have this hyperlink in my parent page. by clicking it i send values using sessions to the pop up page.i use the hyperlink target to the _blank page. In pop up page i generate a itemId and view it using label.

```
<asp:Label id="lblMatNo" runat="server" BackColor="Silver"></asp:Label></td>

<asp:Button id="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" Text="Add Material" />
```

if i click the btnadd button i want to send lblMatNo text value to the parent page & set the value to 
`<asp:TextBox id="txtMatId" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox></td>` text field.

currently i have selected values in my dropdownlists. i need to get the item id to the same parent page that having dropdownlist values without change.

i need to close the pop up window when i click the btnAdd button.

can i do this. or if its wrong how can i do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send values to parent page then you can use

[window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener)

> Returns a reference to the window that
>   opened this current window.

```
var objRef = window.opener;
objRef.document.getElementById("txtMatId").value = passed value;
```

To get the selected value from the drop down list

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("yourdropdownid");
var selectedValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.options.selectedIndex].value;
```

If you need to close the pop up window then you can use

```
self.close()
```

from the pop up window button click. This closes the current window

Comment: +1 for the reference link, good code example on usage as well